# Ruby Iterating TkButton

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

For those who work with GUIs,

I'm creating a button that creates additional labels within the root window with a click of a button but that also unpacks these labels with an additional click (similar to the everyday expand/collapse button functionality)

I've written the code with a nested command proc structure:

```
 matrix = TkButton.new(root) {
   width 10;
   height 1;
   command proc { e = TkLabel.new(root) { background 'purple' }.grid;
       command proc { e.ungrid } 
   }
 }
```

The code works but the problem is that the command proc becomes obsolete after two clicks. How can I iterate this so that the button works at all times?